# How to make calendar default to "Expand All" view?

Tags: 2007, web-part, calendar

I have a single page on our site that I would like to load in the "Expanded" view (show all tasks without the "Expand All" option that hides anything over the maximum number). So far I've only seen the following methods for doing this in 2007:

1. Use javascript to call `GetMonthView('11111111');` which is the way the calendar does it by default.
2. Change some template file that has a setting for max number of tasks to show by default (seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/syedi/how-to-customize-a-calendar-to-show-more-events-in-a-monthly-chrome-view-in-wss-3-0-moss-sharepoint-2007)).

With option 1, the javascript simply posts some data back to the server as if the user had clicked the link. This causes a page reload when you first load the calendar which IMO is very unclean. With option 2, the template seems to be the default setting for the entire site, when I only want to change an individual calendar view. I am extremely new to sharepoint development, so I'm lost on how I can accomplish this. Can anyone provide some insight? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Those are really the only ways to do this in 2007. I have built a lot of code around making a workweek only view and it really boils down to how SharePoint draws the calendar. The postback will cause a page refresh and that is how it works. I really do not think there is a better answer that. The only other possibility is to maybe try a 3rd party calendar tool or build your own which may or may not be the best answer for you.